# How do I change the color depth of a monitor in Lion/10.7?

Tags: macos, display

How do I change the color depth of a monitor in Lion/10.7? I vague remember it being an option in the display prefs or the display menu bar in an older OSX version, but it seems gone in 10.7?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the Quicksilver Displays plugin changes color depth for Lion as well. If you use Quicksilver already (and you should) its very easy - search for the display name, choose the color depth action, and choose the depth you want. It's great for changing display size also.

A little more info is here - http://lifehacker.com/322363/top-10-quicksilver-plug+ins.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in that Apple removed the option to switch between "Millions" and "Thousands" of colors from the Displays preference pane in OS X after Leopard (10.5).

I've not tried them, but something like [Display Maestro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-maestro/id414546485?mt=12) or [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/functions/menus/menus.html) both appear to have the ability to change color depth and might help.

Comment: Thanks! Display Maestro seems to work, SwitchResX does not seem to have a color depth option in Lion.